# What does "by sight" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adverbs

> They know him well **by sight**.

Could you explain that what does "**by sight**" here ?

Comment: Did you check any dictionaries @Hasan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[By sight:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by-sight)

> by appearance; by recognizing but not through being acquainted.

(Collins Dictionary)

So if you know someon by sight, it means you  can recognize them because you often see them, for instance, but not because you  know them in person.